# JFXtras add listener to dragging appointment

Tags: java, javafx, jfxtras

I cant find any information on the JFXtras JavaDoc on how to add a listener for when you click and drag an appointment. Is it possible to do this? Or anyway to disable dragging of appointments?

My appointments are taken directly from a database so when a user drags it shows a different time on their Agenda than the appointment is stored as on the database, hence I want to catch when they drag the appointment.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When appointments are dragged, their start and end time are updated and the agenda is rerendered. It currently is not possible to prevent dragging (good feature, would you mind creating an issue on github for that?), but you can simply not accept the new start and end times in the respective setters.

If you have used the default Appointment implementations, than this is not easily possible. The best way is to have your own class implementing Appointment.

Comment: I've added allowDragging and allowResize properties to 8.0-r4-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one thing I noticed with the allowDragging property is that I am unable to click and select an appointment with it set to false.

Comment: Creating the listeners in the Appointment solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: Ah, indeed, selecting is handled by the same logic as dragging. Thanks for testing that. #neverMakeChangesBeforeBreakfast